# Why doesn't King use Fossilization on Hendrick and The Albion?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the Capital of the Dead, King uses Chastiefol's Form Three, Fossilization on

> Ban the immortal

and it works effectively.

Why doesn't King use Fossilization on Hendrick and The Albion then?

Answer (score 1):

King tried to use Fossilization on Dawn Roar's member, Hugo in manga chapter 54 (anime season 1, episode 14), but Simon just cut the arm off.

Hendrickson would just cut it off then heal himself with his new Demon powers. The Albion probably would just smash its own arm off before it fully petrifies him, since it spreads so slowly. So, petrification wouldn't be all that effective.

In the Capital of the Dead, it worked on him because he didn't care about being petrified. He was smiling the whole time, remember?